# assign a value to checkbox in a grid header

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, code-behind

I have following grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDWlocations" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" runat="server" GridLines="None" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
    EmptyDataText="No data found..." AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="true">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="allDWlocchk" runat="server" Checked="true" Width="10px" onclick="CheckAllgrdReqDW(this)"></asp:CheckBox>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_DWlocReq" runat="server" Checked="true" Width="5px" OnCheckedChanged="chk_Req_CheckedChangedDW_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_DWCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ml_loc_cd") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_DWDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ml_loc_desc") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to assign a value for 'allDWlocchk' which is header check,

how  can I do this in code behind

I tried this none of the thing worked

Attempt 1  :

```
((CheckBox)(grdDWlocations).FindControl("allDWlocchk")).Checked = false;
```

Attempt 2  :

```
((CheckBox).FindControl("allDWlocchk")).Checked = false;
```

Comment: Your checkbox is not in header but in row. Thats what your code say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, `FindControl` is the way to go here. But the problem is that it only works with direct children. So instead of searching on the Page or on the GridView you need to be searching in the header row. Which is available as the GridView property. So:

```
GridViewRow headerRow = grdDWlocations.HeaderRow;
((CheckBox)headerRow.FindControl("allDWlocchk")).Checked = false;
```